# wordpress - Custom author template replaced part of home page

Tags: wordpress

I came across a weird problem while developing a custom author template for my wordpress project.I used the below code to change the default template to custom template for author page.

```
function author_template_change($template) {
$template = um_product_path . 'users/templates/user-profile.php';
return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include','author_template_change');
```

where `um_product_path` is plugin directory path.
Now the problem is after I successfully coded some part of the template, the template contents started replacing my home page parts. Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: any help that I can get on this please?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it using the answer here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155871/create-template-author-with-a-plugin. What I missed in my code is a conditional check if the current page is author's page or not. Thanks to helgatheviking.